# Quadratic Formula: Any Shortcomings?

Tags: quadratics

I was wondering, if when solving a quadratic equation where factoring wasn't helpful in finding a solution, if there were any cases in which using the quadratic formula would generate results that would not solve the equation?  My understanding is that the quadratic formula tends to be a shortcut in using the method of 'completing the square' and I wondered if there were any way in which to discern when using these methods that they would not resolve in a constructive solution, other than those involving imaginary numbers(multiples of the square root of -1)?

Comment: It fails in characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 1):

In doing numerical computations, the quadratic formula can in some cases produce "catastrophic cancellation" where you subtract two numbers that are very close together, resulting in a large relative error.  For example, consider

$$  10^{-20} x^2 + x + 1 = 0 $$

Your calculator is likely to get $\sqrt{b^2 - 4 a c} = 1.0$, resulting in a root of $0$.  But in fact the root near $0$ is approximately $-1$.

Comment: I do not use calculators to perform square roots.